# How to continue messaging content script from extension after tab URL has changed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to continue to send messages to the content script to run different functions given a URL. Whenever I go to a new URL the messaging stops. How can I make it so the messaging pauses when the new tab URL is loading and then continue on when the tab has loaded?

**popup.js**

```
function begin(params) {

    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
        console.log("connecting");
        var port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[0].id, {name: "testing"});
        port.postMessage({test: "test1"});
        port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
            if (msg.response == "test1 received") {
                console.log(msg.response);
                port.postMessage({test: "test2"});
            } else if (msg.response == "test2 received") {
                console.log(msg.response);
                port.postMessage({test : "test3"});
            } else if (msg.response == "test3 received") {
                console.log(msg.response);
                port.postMessage({test : "test4"});
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**contentscript.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  console.assert(port.name == "testing");
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.test === "test1") {
        console.log(msg.test);
        // Do stuff and click on new url //
        port.postMessage({response: "test1 received"});

    } else if (msg.test === "test2") {
        console.log(msg.test);
        // Do stuff and click on new url //
        port.postMessage({response: "test2 recieved"});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to re-establish the connections, since as per the description of the [official guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#port-lifetime), a connection is closed in the following situations:

> - There are no listeners for `runtime.onConnect` at the other end.
> - **The tab containing the port is unloaded (e.g. if the tab is navigated).**
> - The frame from where connect was called has unloaded.
> - All frames that received the port (via `runtime.onConnect`) have unloaded.
> - `runtime.Port.disconnect` is called by the other end. Note that if a connect call results in multiple ports at the receiver's end, and `disconnect()` is called on any of these ports, then the `onDisconnect` event is only fired at the port of the sender, and not at the other ports.

Comment: So how can I reestablish connection when navigating to a new URL in a tab? Should I be adding a listener on the popup.js for onDisconnect and then wait till a connection is reestablished with the given name?

Comment: @LatentFreedom, one question, every time the web page is reloaded, usually popup page will be closed, do you want to manually open the popup page once the page is reloaded? Why not put it in background page?

Comment: I guess I do not really understand the background page. I wanted to take a clothing item on a page and click on it. then go to the next opened page and input a good size and then go to checkout. Then I want to go through the checkout process.

Comment: @LatentFreedom, where is the 'clothing item'? in the current web page or popup page? 'input a good size', where did that happen, popup page or current web page? When I'm saying popup page, I mean something like https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#popups

Comment: Everything is on the webpage so I can just send values to the elements on the page. There are no popup pages.

Comment: @LatentFreedom, then you mean `popup.js` is actually a content script?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. popup.js is launched from popup.html which is the page for the chrome extension.

Comment: @LatentFreedom, if that logic is in `popup.js`, then that means every time the tab is reloaded, you would need to reopen popup page to establish connections; however, if the logic has nothing related with popup UI page, then you could just move that to background page, that would save the extra step to open the popup page.